# AngularJS loading HTML div content on demand

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on a implementation which retrieves data from the server and updates the data model at the client browser [one way data binding]. The structure of the data model is mentioned below.

Further to this data model, i am displaying the content as follows

[image]

The structure is that summary div which contains summary of service executed. On click of summary div individual service data can be seen [used accordian]. This worked perfectly. However, if the number of services increases or if the depth of the service chain increases the responsiveness becomes very slow. The data can be assumed as big data. Also, the services can be added at any point. Based on this the summary needs to be updated.

Did anyone faced this challenge and what was the approach to the same. I am planning to do this with lazy loading of the div on demand. Any pointers on lazy loading?

Comment: My suggestion is to have a different service for sub-tree (inside accordion) and just when the user needed to see and clicked on an accordion, then grab the sub-tree list!

Comment: Do you use track by with ng-repeat? It may impact seriously on the perfomance.

Comment: use infinite scroll, try to avoid watchers or if you can use one way data binding. The most important thing is to avoid watchers

Comment: @Andrei, Current implementation uses ng-repeat for the summary and for each item in the list i use ng-include html to display the child content. On this i am planning to include laze loading.

Comment: Update: I tried with lazy loading and the implementation worked for the data set in my local box [which was less than 10MB in totality]. But when i tried in the actual scenario which emits more than 500MB of data, javascript memory overflows. I am planning to make use of IndexDB to address this. Any pointer on angularJS and IndexDB for Big data problem would help. Otherwise this question is answered and thanks everyone for the time spent on this.

Answer (score 0):

For lazy rendering you can use ng-if with one way binding

```
<div ng-if="::shouldRender" ng-show="shouldRender">
</div>
```

Div will render when shouldRender become true, and will not be destroyed, when shouldRender becomes false.

Comment: @Kozlov, thanks for the snippet. Lazy loading worked for me.